# Can I use turrets but still get the "Ghost" experience points?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm currently playing through Deus Ex: Human Revolution with the intent of using stealth. But I'm noticing that there's an option for me to use the enemy turrets and robots against them at certain times.

Can I use these without losing the chance to earn the "Ghost" XP?

Also, for the game achievement of not getting seen do the following count?

- Any Boss Fight?
- Causing "Alarmed" Status
- Being seen by turrents and enemy cameras?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a list of what will NOT lose your ghost bonus

- Enemies being alerted to your presence (alarmed status), but not yet hostile. This includes actions like opening doors, luring enemies away from the spot they are guarding with a distraction, killing an enemy with one fatal shot, and take downs (from behind or a concealed spot).
- Being seen by a camera (i.e., it turns hostile) - as long as you aren't also seen by the turrets/guards/bots that are alerted by the resulting alarm.
- Failing to hack, which triggers an alarm. Again, you are OK as long as
  you don't get spotted by the investigators of the alarm.
- **Hacking a turret/bot to attack other enemies** (you will lose the Pacifist achievement by doing this however).
- Using instant-knockout weapons such as EMP grenade against turrets/bots or gas grenade against human adversaries as long as no one witnesses you doing so. In other words, do this when no one is watching and/or don't leave survivors.
- Do not let enemies see the bodies of their associates or a bot
  exploding.
- Shooting an enemy while cloaked. This will possibly turn the rest in the area hostile briefly, You should be OK provided that you are hidden from view when you decloak and of course, they don't find the body. I don't recommend this however.
- Boss fights are an exception as you can't skip them, so they do not make you lose the Ghost XP.

Comment: To clarify, the reason hacking the turret/bot does not lose you the Ghost bonus, yet might appear to do so, is because you will lose the bonus if anyone sees the bodies left by the turret/bot. Against the last guard, or a lone guard, it's fine.